# CF7 Email submitted converted in UPPERCASE except email and url

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, hook, contact-form-7

I have this hook to convert all user input to uppercase in notification emails, the code in functions.php is the one below.
Is there any way to implement the code to exclude the EMAIL and URL fields, how can I do it?
I’m newbie with php so I don’t know precisely the syntax and tags.
Thanks

Here is the code I tried to convert all user input to uppercase

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced',
 
  function( $replaced, $submitted, $html, $mail_tag ) {
    if ( is_string( $submitted ) ) {
      $replaced = strtoupper( $submitted );
    }
 
    return $replaced;
  },
 
  10, 4
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this code change but the form is not submitted when clicking submit. Where is the problem?

Thank you

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced',
 
  function( $replaced, $submitted, $html, $mail_tag ) {
    if ( is_string( $submitted ) ) {
      $replaced = strtoupper( $submitted );
    }
    if ( 'EMAIL' == $mail_tag->field_name() ) {
        if ( is_string( $submitted ) ) {
            $replaced = strtolower( $submitted );
        }
    }
    return $replaced;
  },
 
  10, 4
);
```